# Where is OpenGLConfig.cmake located on mac?

Tags: opengl, cmake-gui

I'm using OpenGL with a C++ project. When I run configure in cmake-gui I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenGL" with any
of the following names:

OpenGLConfig.cmake
opengl-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "OpenGL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"OpenGL_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenGL"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
```

Presumably, I have to set the OpenGL_DIR value but I can't find where OpenGLConfig.cmake file is located on mac.

Comment: This should come with your CMake installation. How did you install CMake?

Comment: @flyx I downloaded the .dmg file from https://cmake.org/download/ for macOS 10.13 or later

Comment: Please show your code.